# Kafka MockConsumer not receiving records

Tags: clojure, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm writing against the new kafka consumer API in 0.9 using java interop in clojure. I've had success so far but now I'm trying to write some unit tests with `MockConsumer` and `MockProducer`. My test always fails because `(first values)` is `nil`.

I don't understand why the consumer isn't seeing any of the messages that the producer is sending to the topic.

```
(ns blah
  (:require [cheshire.core :as json]
            [clojure.test :refer [is testing deftest]])
  (:import [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer MockConsumer OffsetResetStrategy]
           [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer MockProducer]
           [org.apache.kafka.common.serialization StringSerializer]
           [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer KafkaConsumer ConsumerRecords ConsumerRecord]
           [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer KafkaProducer ProducerRecord]
           [java.util ArrayList]))

(defn send-message
  [producer topic value]
  (let [pr (ProducerRecord. topic value)]
    (.send producer pr)))

(defn messages
  "Return seq of messages from consumer."
  ([consumer] (messages consumer 100))
  ([consumer timeout]
   (println "poll consumer for messages")
   (let [records (seq (.poll consumer timeout))]
     (when records
       (map record->map records)))))

(deftest consuming
  (let [c (MockConsumer. (OffsetResetStrategy/EARLIEST))
        _ (.subscribe c (doto (ArrayList.) (.add "unittest")))
        p (MockProducer. true (StringSerializer.) (StringSerializer.))]
    (send-message p "unittest" (json/generate-string {:a 1 :b "two"}))
    (let [values (seq (messages c))]
      (is (= {:a 1 :b "two"}
          (first values))))
    (.close c)
    (.close p)))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MockProducer is designed to unit test that a class/function is producing the expected messages. For example:

```
(deftest producing
  (let [p (MockProducer. true (StringSerializer.) (StringSerializer.))]
    (send-message p "unittest" (json/generate-string {:a 1 :b "two"}))
    (let [values (.history p)]
      (is (= {:a 1 :b "two"}
             (json/parse-string (.value (first values)) true))))
    (.close p)))
```

Note the call to [the history method](https://apache.googlesource.com/kafka/+/0.9.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/MockProducer.java#166)

Similar the MockConsumer has the [addRecord method](https://apache.googlesource.com/kafka/+/0.9.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/MockConsumer.java#166) to setup your test case for consumers.

As you can see MockConsumer and MockProducer are completely unrelated and designed to be used in isolation.

If what you want to test is a full roundtrip, you will probably be more interested on starting an embedded Kafka using something like [this](https://ransilberman.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/how-to-unit-test-kafka/)